# How to tell when PyCharm saves file?

Tags: pycharm

I am new to PyCharm and am trying to figure out when it saves my files. There is no indicator (like in Notepad++ for example) showing that the file has been modified. How do I tell when it has been saved vs modified?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By default PyCharm will save files whenever you switch apps. If you want to see which files it hasn't saved yet, there is a config options for this under "Settings" -> "Editor" -> "General" -> "Editor Tabs" you can check the "Mark modified (*)" option.

Below you can find a screenshot of the setting taken in PyCharm 2020.2:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "switch apps"?

Comment: Giving focus to another app (e.g. by cmd-tab or alt-tab).

Comment: What a stupid behavior - should be asterisk by default like everywhere.

Comment: I suggest that you should update the steps for PyCharm 2018.1.2 (Community Edition). Many thanks.

Comment: @trdngy I'm looking at CE 2018.1.2 right now and the procedure looks exactly the same to me. What do you think is different?

Comment: It doesn't show you by default, but you can change the settings. In Pycharm CE 2018.2, go to File --> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Editor Tabs Then check the **Mark modified (*)** box under the Appearance heading.

Comment: Dangerous and unexpected behaviour, caveat of PyCharm. I would like to save only when I want to.

Answer (score 0):

In pyCharm version 2023.3.2 I used the Help ...Find Action to search for "Editor Tabs" to find the necessary check box for "Mark Modified". The editor then displayed a circle symbol in the file tab to indicate the file had not yet been saved, which changed to an x symbol after saving the file.